# Unable to check if a javascript checkbox array element is checked or not?

Tags: javascript, checkbox

What is want is - when the checkbox is checked option no. 5 in select list will be selected and when the checkbox is unchecked option no. 0 will be selected in the select list.

The select list and the checkboxes are generated dynamically in the php code as below :

```
echo "<select name='coupons".$i."' id='coupons".$i."'>";
------- All Options --------
echo "</select>";


<input type='checkbox' name='myCheckbox[]' value='<?php echo $i."_".$row->id; ?>' onclick='setCCode("myCheckbox[]",<?php echo $i;?>)'> 

 -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Solved the second requirement on my own now ..... thanks to all for your inputs

just added the following line in the `checkAll()` within the `for loop`

```
setCCode(children[i],i+1);
```

The javascript function :

```
function setCCode(checkbox_name,i) 
{   
    var form_object = document.getElementsByName(checkbox_name+"["+i+"]");
    var selname = document.getElementsByName("coupons"+i)[0];

    if(form_object.checked) {
            selname.selectedIndex = 5;
    }
    else {
        selname.selectedIndex = 0;
    } 
}
```

The above issue is solved....... thanks to all

Now what i need to do is when a user checks a checkbox to select or deselect all the dynamically generated checkboxes on the form the above logic should work.

```
<input type='checkbox' name='checkall' onChange="checkAll(this, 'myCheckbox[]')">
<span class="chkall">Check / Uncheck All</span>

<input type='checkbox' name='myCheckbox[]' value='<?php echo $i."_".$row->id; ?>' onclick='setCCode(this,<?php echo $i;?>)'>
```

The javascript code i am using to select/deselect all checkboxes on form is as below :

```
function checkAll(parent, field)
{
    var children = document.getElementsByName(field);
    var newValue = parent.checked;

    for (i = 0; i < children.length; i++){
    if (children[i].disabled == false) {    
        children[i].checked = newValue;
    }
    }
}

function setCCode(Sender,i) 
{   
  document.getElementsByName("coupons"+i)[0].selectedIndex = Sender.checked ? 5 : 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass refference to the checkbox itself as a parameter

```
<input type='checkbox' name='myCheckbox[]' value='<?php echo $i."_".$row->id; ?>' onclick='setCCode(this,<?php echo $i;?>)'>

function setCCode(Sender,i) 
{   
  document.getElementsByName("coupons"+i)[0].selectedIndex = Sender.checked ? 5 : 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

getElementsByName returns an array of objects. Replace the line with:

```
var form_object = document.getElementsByName(checkbox_name+"["+i+"]")[0];
```

Comment: getting the error message as below when i am doing what u suggested Error: form_object is undefined
Source File: http://localhost:82/rajib/admin/free_members_ajax.php
Line: 71

Answer (score 0):

If you have a reference to the form that the checkbox is in, and it has a unique name in the form, then you can access it as:

```
form_object = form.elements[ checkbox_name + "[" + i + "]" ];
```

and you can also use the ternary operator to make the code more concise:

```
selname.selectedIndex = form_object.checked? 5 : 0;
```

#### Edit

Sorry, missed the obvious. If you pass a refereference to the checkbox in the handler, then you can also get the form (all form controls have a *form* property that references the form they are in). So as Jan Pfeifer suggested (abbreviated markup):

```
<input ... onclick='setCCode(this, <?php echo $i;?>)'>
```

then the script is just:

```
function setCCode(checkbox, i) 
{   
    checkbox.form.elements['coupons' + i].selectedIndex = checkbox.checked? 5 : 0;
}
```

Comment: Error: form_object is undefined
Source File: http://localhost:82/rajib/admin/free_members_ajax.php
Line: 72

function setCCode(checkbox_name,i) 
{ 
 var form_object = document.forms[0].elements[ checkbox_name + "[" + i + "]" ];
    var selname = document.getElementsByName("coupons"+i)[0];
 selname.selectedIndex = form_object.checked? 5 : 0;
}

Comment: Did you assign a reference to the form to the variable *form* first as specified?